# Mac Excel Control Shift RIght Arrow

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

It's been a while since I used Excel on a PC.

In Excel on a PC, I believe if you have a set of data and want to select all the cells in the same row from where the cursor is to the last cell below a set of data, you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>←</kbd>. On a Mac (Excel 2011) this selects all the cells until the end of the entire row.

Using Excel 2011 (Mac), how can I select all the empty cells in a row until beneath a set of data?

The reason for doing this is if I want to copy the current row and paste that to another row of data. I should be able to copy the current row, then hit down, then (I thought) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>←</kbd>, then paste and I would paste in another set of data.

Comment: I'm shocked it has been over 6 years and there is still no solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

I found it:  <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option (Alt)</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

"Command" "Shift" "Arrow" on Mac can do the same as "Ctrl" "Shift" "Arrow" on PC.

Answer (score -1):

On my Mac the shortcut is ctrl+shift+dirKey OR cmd+shift+dirKey
MBP 2017.
//Permki

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This answer has no context because you don't state the type or year of Mac you have.  See [answer] for info on how to provide good answers.  Then, you can [edit] your answer to add the missing info.  - From Review